# Build objectiveflickr for ios6 error

Tags: xcode, ios6

My project using objectiveflickr library, I am building the project on Xcode 4.6, targeting iPhone 5.

When I run the project, I got this error:

> No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7 i386).

I've tried to change the arch, active arch only, still cannot fix it.

Comment: have you tried adding armv7s to the valid archs?

Comment: @tttthomasssss Yes I tried.